# Log4Net not working when using configuration file

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to use `log4net` in my current project.
So I started to read examples from the official documentation and first played a bit with the `BasicConfigurator` but the next step is to switch to a configuration file instead of hardcoding everything.
I created a `XML` file called `MyApp.log4net` containing:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

The config file is located in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Next I added

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "MyApp.log4net", Watch = true)]
namespace Awesome.Server
{
    class Program
    {
        ...
```

to the `Program` class which is located in the same directory as `MyApp.log4net`.
If I now try to log someting e.g. using...

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)).Info("Hello World");
```

...then nothing happens. No error, no message, nothing.
Is there anything I forgot/misunderstood about how this works that would fix this?

Comment: The config file full name needs to be set in ConfigFile, i.e. `MyApp.log4net.xml`

Comment: I set up a fresh console application with the assembly attribute and config file and logged a hello world. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

You specified the configuration file's name to be "Awesome.Server.log4net":

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Awesome.Server.log4net", Watch = true)]
namespace Awesome.Server {
    ...
}
```

Either fix your config file name or change the assembly attribute property `ConfigFile`.